# What type of algorithm would this be called?

Tags: algorithm

What type of algorithm would this be called? Is it any sorting algorithm or bruteforce algorithm?

```
boolean isPrime = true;

for(int i=2; i<=number/2; i++){
    if(number%i == 0){
        isPrime = false;
        break;
    }              
}

if(isPrime){
    System.out.println("Prime");
}
System.out.println("Not Prime");
```

Comment: it is brute force, no any kind of sorting here

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm apparently tests the variable `number` for primality by using all smaller numbers as potential factors; the approach could be considered brute-force.